What is the issue with my JWT authorization algorithm in my ASP.NET application for implementing push notifications?
For the past couple of days, I've been following this article on making my own JWT signatures required for web push notifications to be validated by the push service. Example code is written in JavaScript but I've written out a solution within the ASP.NET Core MVC web application to the best of my abilities:
[ActionName("trigger-push-message")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> triggerPushMessage() {
        var first = _context.Subscribers.First();
        
        string jwt_aud, jwt_exp, jwt_sub;
        jwt_aud = first.Endpoint.Substring(0,1+first.Endpoint.IndexOf('/',8));
        jwt_exp = (((DateTimeOffset)DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeSeconds() + 12 * 60 * 60).ToString();
        jwt_sub = "mailto:emailhere@example.com";

        var jwt1 = new {typ = "JWT", alg = "ES256"};
        var jwt2 = new {aud = jwt_aud, exp = jwt_exp, sub = jwt_sub};
        
        string base64_1 = Base64Url.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(jwt1)));
        string base64_2 = Base64Url.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(jwt2)));
        byte[] unsigned_token = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64_1 + "." + base64_2);
        
        byte[] public_key = Base64Url.Base64UrlDecode("BNIL96_6318XSC6iGF8pOxThvifLMvN5DHtwHwPKSgki0r6QzOvbxGJ6bg6yPu0fJ9aqml-YXpA0UybWvvjeVwc");
        byte[] private_key = Base64Url.Base64UrlDecode("gOQ-7RPtxyDdJvMMbc0KrCNyDWaZw60Hmf8T-eHTjqw");
        byte[] public_key_x = new byte[32];
        byte[] public_key_y = new byte[32];
        Array.Copy(public_key, 1, public_key_x, 0, 32);
        Array.Copy(public_key, 33, public_key_y, 0, 32);

        var ecParameters = new ECParameters
        {
            Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256,
            D = private_key,
            Q =
            new ECPoint {
                X = public_key_x,
                Y = public_key_y,
            }
        };

        using (var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(ecParameters))
        {
            // Sign the data
            byte[] signatureBytes = ecdsa.SignData(unsigned_token, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

            // Base64 URL encode the signature
            string signature = Base64Url.Base64UrlEncode(signatureBytes);

            Console.WriteLine("Signature: " + signature);
            Console.WriteLine("JWT: " + base64_1 + "." + base64_2 + "." + signature);
        }


        return NoContent();
    }

And here's the custom Base64Url encoder and decoder I've written up within a class.
public class Base64Url {
  public static byte[] Base64UrlDecode(string input)
  {
      string base64 = input.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
      switch (base64.Length % 4)
      {
          case 2: base64 += "=="; break;
          case 3: base64 += "="; break;
      }
      return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
  }

  public static string Base64UrlEncode(byte[] input)
  {
      return Convert.ToBase64String(input)
          .TrimEnd('=')
          .Replace('+', '-')
          .Replace('/', '_');
  }
}

The private and public keys provided are an example. I am not using these keys.
I got the VAPID keys from this website and inserted it as a string literal as I just want to create a prototype to test out push notifications. I've also tried new VAPID keys twice. I did not forget to subscribe with this new key from the client side.
Everything should work correctly, I've been reading though the data using the debugger within VSCode. Unfortunately, the JWT returned from the console always returns invalid when I test it out on jwt.io. If I send a web push request to the endpoint through Postman, I get this response (I've double checked "Authorization" and "Crypto-Key" headers):
{
    "code": 401,
    "errno": 109,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unknown auth scheme",
    "more_info": "http://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#error-codes"
}

I have also tried using other types of keys by converting the JSON Web Key into PEM formatting using this website to no avail.

If I understand correctly, the JWT generated by your C# code is not successfully verified on jwt.io. I cannot reproduce this. A possible problem is that you are using the wrong key or the key in the wrong format. The jwt.io public key field says: Public Key in SPKI, PKCS #1, X.509 Certificate, or JWK string format. Does this apply to your key? Post sample data: JWT and key used on jwt.io.

Essentially, the ECParameters instance within the code acts as the JSON Web Key. It just doesn't store the X, Y and D as Base64Url data but instead as byte arrays.
Still, I can produce a key using the JsonSerializer and my base64url encoder:
Sample key: {"kty":"EC","crv":"P-256","x":"0gv3r_rfXxdILqIYXyk7FOG-J8sy83kMe3AfA8pKCSI","y":"0r6QzOvbxGJ6bg6yPu0fJ9aqml-YXpA0UybWvvjeVwc","d":"gOQ-7RPtxyDdJvMMbc0KrCNyDWaZw60Hmf8T-eHTjqw"}
Signature: vc5_P_oo1Z_IW2rjRxl8HkMvczYEPIkKGPRnwDjLC2iMfaox8cZy0JbPPaVtrK716-TwK4iCY4RKPq9REoJJxw

JWT: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3VwZGF0ZXMucHVzaC5zZXJ2aWNlcy5tb3ppbGxhLmNvbS8iLCJleHAiOiIxNzIzNjY5NzMwIiwic3ViIjoibWFpbHRvOmxlbW9uNHNvdXJAZ21haWwuY29tIn0.vc5_P_oo1Z_IW2rjRxl8HkMvczYEPIkKGPRnwDjLC2iMfaox8cZy0JbPPaVtrK716-TwK4iCY4RKPq9REoJJxw

Please do not post this data in comments, as this is difficult to read. Instead, edit your question and add the data at the end. I may be misunderstanding the problem, but the posted JWT is successfully verified with this JWK (with and without d), see link in the following comment.

Verification with jwt.io

Looks like it was a simple case of RTFM. I've been passing the Authorization header with the quotation marks as stated in the article I was reading, but that appears to be wrong. In the same article the "exp" value in the payload was also passed as a string instead of a number, giving me these errors. Thank you for your help!

Looks like it was a simple case of RTFM. I've been passing the Authorization header with the quotation marks as stated in the article I was reading, but that appears to be wrong. In the same article the "exp" value in the payload was also passed as a string instead of a number, giving me these errors. Thank you for your help!
I also foolishly assumed just pasting the JWT was enough to validate it, I also needed to pass a JWK into the verification box on the right.
